# Excel to PDF, multiple ranges same sheet (string) but PrintArea 255 string limit

Tags: excel, vba

I believe ranges have a 255 character limit, so I've split the ranges up in 6 cells
B1 through B6 (cell B1 and cell B2 examples below both well below 255 characters).

```
A1:I15, A17:I40, A42:I65, A92:I114, A116:I140, A142:I168, A170:I196, A198:I224, A226:I252, A254:I280, A282:I308, A310:I336, A338:I364, A366:I392, A394:I420, A422:I448

A450:I476, A478:I504, A526:I552, A554:I580, A582:I608, A610:I636, A638:I664, A666:I690, A692:I707, A730:I750, A752:I773, A775:I794, A796:I815, A817:I830, A855:I877, A879:I905, A907:I926
```

I tried the Union function to generate a PDF from these ranges but somehow I am only getting the ranges from B1! B2 gets ignored. Here's my code:

```
Set rng = Union(shTemp.Range("B1"), shTemp.Range("B2"))

shTransformed.Activate
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PrintArea = rng
 End With

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:="c:\temp\test.pdf", _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: just change 1st line to `Dim RngStr As String`  and
`RngStr = shTemp.Range("B1").Value & "," & shTemp.Range("B2").Value` and ` .PrintArea = RngStr`

Comment: @AhmedAU When I use a concatenated string I get the error `unable to set the PrintArea property of the PageSetup class`. When I just use one of the ranges it works. I think it's because of the 255 string limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May use this workaround to bypass 255 character limit of print area range address by adding Horizontal page breaks and hiding the rows in between print areas. However it is applicable in this case only as the right most column in each print areas are same (i.e. I) and also this method requires each print areas is to be separated by at least a row.

It is tested successfully with the range string as defined in OP. Make some modification regarding Sheets name, range etc.

```
Sub test()
Dim shTemp As Worksheet, shTr As Worksheet
Dim HideRng As Range, Rng As Range, MainRng As Range
Dim Ar As Range, cel As Range
Set shTemp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set shTr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)

'To Dynamically Select Range containing Addresses
Dim SelRng As Range
Set SelRng = shTemp.Range("B1:B6")  ' Default range
shTemp.Activate
On Error Resume Next
Set SelRng = Application.InputBox("Select the range containing Print Range Addresses", "Select Range", SelRng.Address, , , , , 8)
    If Err > 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
If SelRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cel In SelRng.Cells
        If cel.Value <> "" Then
        If Not Range(cel.Value) Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print Range(cel.Value).Address
            If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = Range(cel.Value)
            Else
            Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range(cel.Value))
            End If
        End If
        End If
    Next

If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With shTr
 .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
pg = 1
maxcol = 1
    For Each Ar In Rng.Areas
        'Vartical Pagebreak: it is applicable only in this case where right column is same
        If pg = 1 Then
        Set MainRng = Ar(1, 1)
        .VPageBreaks.Add Ar(1, Ar.Columns.Count).Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    'Ar(1, 1).Value = "Page " & pg
    .HPageBreaks.Add Ar(Ar.Rows.Count, Ar.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
        If pg > 1 Then
        If HideRng(HideRng.Rows.Count, 1).Row < Ar(1, 1).Row Then
        Set HideRng = Range(HideRng, Ar(1, 1).Offset(-1, 0))
        HideRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        End If
    Set HideRng = Ar(Ar.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0)
    If pg = Rng.Areas.Count Then Set MainRng = Range(MainRng, Ar(Ar.Rows.Count, Ar.Columns.Count))
    pg = pg + 1
    Next
End With

shTr.Activate
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PrintArea = MainRng.Address
 End With

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
 Type:=xlTypePDF, _
 Filename:="c:\users\user\Desktop\test.pdf", _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

[Screen Shot of created PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXzWB.jpg)

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically go through the ranges instead of `Set Rng = Union(shTr.Range(shTemp.Range("B1").Value), shTr.Range(shTemp.Range("B2").Value))`?

Comment: It appears that page 11 and 12 are blank, and this behavior repeats throughout the pages. Every 9 or 10 pages. I'm having trouble finding the cause in your code

Comment: Do you mean to go through range B2 to B6 containing range addresses? I re-checked through all the 33 pages of PDF and none found blank.

Comment: Yes, the B column will contain range addresses B1 through B## (any number is possible). I am using the code as is but for some reason it hides the 11th and 12th range (A254:I280, A282:I308) and again the 22th and 23th and so on.

Comment: obtaining range addresses through B1 through is quite possible but at present could not figure out reason for blank pages even after multiple trials.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why it's happening on my side, but I went another way. I took your code and changed it. Instead of hiding what I don't use, I hide all rows at the start and unhide what I use. Will post altered code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Ahmed AU's code didn't work 100% for me so I changed it a little. Instead of hiding the rows I don't use I unhide the rows I use.

```
With shTransformed
    .Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    .VPageBreaks.Add shTransformed.Range("J1")

    For Each Ar In Rng.Areas
        .Range(Ar.Address).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        .HPageBreaks.Add Ar(Ar.Rows.Count, Ar.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
    Next Ar
End With

Set MainRng = shTransformed.Range("A" & shTransformed.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row - 1 & ":I" & shTransformed.Cells(shTransformed.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

'Export to PDF code here
```

Comment: Good and simple code.+1,  I always prefer simple code. but still could not figure out  reason for blank pages. Does this code solved the problem? my post updated with  method to dynamically select input.

Comment: Both our method of looping through areas of union range lacks in the regard to handle consecutive print areas (without row gap in between). It will be treated as single page.  So how about exploring possibility of finding through all the rows in the greater print area for some unique text etc identifying start & End of a single (Page) Print Area and add `HPageBreaks` accordingly.

Comment: @AhmedAU I'm not sure what you mean with 'handle consecutive print areas (without row gap in between).' can you give an example?

Comment: If string of ``A1:I15, A16:I41, A42:I65, A92:I114`  areas of range of  will be only `A1:I65` and   `A92:I114`. so in our code  `A1:I65` will be treated as one page and  `A92:I114` as another  page only. Our code is working as there is always 1 or 2 rows gap between intended print areas.

Comment: @AhmedAU I just tested this and I get four pages returned with these ranges `A1:I15, A16:I41, A42:I65, A92:I114`. Either way, there will **always** be at least a one row gap between the ranges :)

Answer (score 0):

`.PrintArea` needs a string instead of a range. So right now, it only takes the value from the first cell of you range, which is B1. You need to concatenate the values themselves and use the concatenated string as value for `.PrintArea`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea

Comment: When I use a concatenated string I get the error `unable to set the PrintArea property of the PageSetup class`. When I just use one of the ranges it works. I think it's because of the 255 string limit.

Comment: It doesn't seem that doing a Union will shorten the string, since the two ranges don't overlap. In that case the address will never be short enough. Isn't it easier to hide the rows that you don't want to print before saving to pdf and show them again afterwards?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not rows in a table I am trying to convert to PDF but rather 'templates'. The ranges each represent one page in the PDF. It could be up to 2000 pages. I am stuck with a workaround, I don't think a solution exist to this 255 string limit to PrintArea. I will post the solution shortly thanks.

Comment: Do the pages have to be in one pdf? Because in that case you can just add pagebreaks to you Worksheet.

Comment: Yes they have to be in a single file, it could be up to 2000 pages (rare). What did you have in mind with the pagebreaks?